# How to create duplicate form from multi dimensional $_POST array

Tags: php, forms, post, foreach

The form I have in a theme is a multi part form and is submitting the following POST data

```
 Array
(
[action] => save
[packageID] => 0
[form] => Array
    (
        [post_title] => Title
        [post_content] => Description
        [category] => 30,35,7
    )

[custom] => Array
    (
        [post_tags] => keyword, key, keys
        [phone_number] => 577XXXXXX
        [price] => 400
        [map_location] => 
        [map-log] => 
        [map-lat] => 
        [map-country] => 
        [map-address1] => 
        [map-address2] => 
        [map-address3] => 
        [map-zip] => 
        [map-state] => 
        [map-city] => 
    )

[check_multi] => 1
)
1
```

I want to create a second form dynamically, using foreach loop and hidden fields where the name of the hidden field will match the $_POST[key] and value of the hidden field will be the value of $_POST[value]

the original form has a name set like this for example

```
name="custom[map-log]"
```

Would I be right in thinking that I can do that for the form keys too for example

```
name="form[post_title]"
```

Points to note, obviously the values will change, but also I wont always know if they keys will be the same so I can't just make a duplicate form and populate it with the POST data I need it created and populated automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Have you tried it yet? Can you share that with us?

Comment: Honestly I haven't because I doubted my own logic and wanted to see i I was on the right tracks before going ahead with it. Every time I have ever sent POST it's always been single dimension, but I've never used multi part forms before. So you think this should just work with a normal foreach loop using the name format above?

Comment: Sure, and if it does or doesn't work you'll learn why and you'll be able to progress from there.

Comment: If you want to hide all the inputs, why not pass in on through a session?

Comment: I don't want to use a session because I don't want to touch the original theme I just want a to run a little interception on the form and post the date back as if it was sent from the original form. If I pass to the session I then have to modify to processing page to read from the session and not post. But I also don't want to hide all of them I want to use the phone number. Send it a code and on confirmation return back to the original form including the verified phone number.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you have any idea about how files are handled. POST data is simple you just pop it back into a text box and resend, what about $_FILES?

Comment: `$_FILES` shouldn't be very different at all.

Comment: Well that's what I thought but you can't just run it into hidden fields otherwise it will be sent with $_POST but I need to loop through the array and send a duplicate. This time I am truly lost with this. Yesterday I had an idea, today I am clueless.

Comment: Try opening a hidden iframe with those form elements duplicated there. I have done that to facilitate file uploads with AJAX forms.

Comment: How would you add the data in because browsers block you form preloading file inputs as you could just steal files from users with hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

OK A huge +1 to Jay Blanchard for your direction. Sometimes it's not getting the help, that helps you it's knowing how to help yourself that gets you there. You were right about it working. I've never seen that format in a form name before but it's very handy. Here is my solution.

```
<?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

   if(is_array ($value)){
      foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue){   ?>
         <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>[<?php echo $subkey; ?>]" value="<?php echo $subvalue; ?>" /><br />
      <?php  }
   } else {   ?>
         <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /><br />
    <?php  }
}
```

And I understand why it works a lot more for having not been spoon fed the answer I was looking for in my tiredness last night.